# How to stitch back cropped image with imageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, crop, image-stitching

I have a big big image, lets name it orig-image.tiff.
I want to cut it in smaller pieces, apply things on it, and stitch back together the newly created little images.

I cut it into pieces with this command :

`convert orig-image.tiff -crop 400x400 crop/parts-%04d.tiff`

then I'll generate many images by applying a treatment to each part-XXXX.tiff image and end up with images from part-0000.png to part-2771.png

Now I want to stitch back the images into a big one. Can imagemagick do that?

Comment: I can not test at the moment but your tiles may still have their original positions on the canvas. Try a test with something like convert part-0000.png part-0001.png -layers merge output.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were using PNG format, the tiles would *"remember"* their original position, as @Bonzo suggests, and you could take them apart and reassemble like this:

```
# Make 256x256 black-red gradient and chop into 1024 tiles of 8x8 as PNGs
convert -size 256x256 gradient:red-black -crop 8x8 tile-%04d.png
```

and reassemble:

```
convert tile*png -layers merge BigBoy.png
```

That is because the tiles *"remember"* their original position on the canvas - e.g. `+248+248` below:

```
identify tile-1023.png
tile-1023.png PNG 8x8 256x256+248+248 16-bit sRGB 319B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

With TIFs, you could do:

```
# Make 256x256 black-red gradient and chop into 1024 tiles of 8x8 as TIFs
convert -size 256x256 gradient:red-black -crop 8x8 tile-%04d.tif
```

and reassemble with the following but sadly you need to know the layout of the original image:

```
montage -geometry +0+0 -tile 32x32 tile*tif BigBoy.tif
```

[image]

---

Regarding Glenn's comment below, here is the output of `pngcheck` showing the *"remembered"* offsets:

```
pngcheck tile-1023*png
```

**Output**

```
OK: tile-1023.png (8x8, 48-bit RGB, non-interlaced, 16.9%).
iMac:~/tmp: pngcheck -v tile-1023*png
File: tile-1023.png (319 bytes)
  chunk IHDR at offset 0x0000c, length 13
    8 x 8 image, 48-bit RGB, non-interlaced
  chunk gAMA at offset 0x00025, length 4: 0.45455
  chunk cHRM at offset 0x00035, length 32
    White x = 0.3127 y = 0.329,  Red x = 0.64 y = 0.33
    Green x = 0.3 y = 0.6,  Blue x = 0.15 y = 0.06
  chunk bKGD at offset 0x00061, length 6
    red = 0xffff, green = 0xffff, blue = 0xffff
  chunk oFFs at offset 0x00073, length 9: 248x248 pixels offset
  chunk tIME at offset 0x00088, length 7: 13 Dec 2016 15:31:10 UTC
  chunk vpAg at offset 0x0009b, length 9
    unknown private, ancillary, safe-to-copy chunk
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x000b0, length 25
    zlib: deflated, 512-byte window, maximum compression
  chunk tEXt at offset 0x000d5, length 37, keyword: date:create
  chunk tEXt at offset 0x00106, length 37, keyword: date:modify
  chunk IEND at offset 0x00137, length 0
No errors detected in tile-1023.png (11 chunks, 16.9% compression).
```

Comment: If you're curious about how tiles "remember" their position, it's contained in the PNG oFFs ("offset") and vpAg ("virtual page") chunks.  The oFFs chunk is defined in the PNG extensions specification while the vpAg chunk is a private chunk invented for ImageMagick.  If you write your PNG file using the ImageMagick "-strip" option, these chunks are omitted from the output and the position is forgotten.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson Many thanks for the explanation - if any other folks are interested, please run `pngcheck -v SomeFile.png` to see the chunks.